# A robotics computer with graphics card, lots of computation power, battery, no screen, no keyboard?

Tags: driver

I'm working on a robotics platform and we need an on-board Ubuntu machine to run ROS image recognition.

Does anyone know of a good set of computer hardware that has

- NO screen
- NO keyboard
- Built-in battery (for charging separate from the robot)
- Quite a bit of compute power (i5+, 4+ GB ram)

I thought about using a laptop, but the keyboard and screen are a lot of extra weight/volume I don't want to carry around. Something like an Intel NUC is appealing, but has no battery.

Comment: How about an Intel NUC attached to a laptop (or whatever) battery?

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Kukanani, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Gigabyte Brix or the Intel NUC are the platforms you're searching for:
http://www.gigabyte.com/products/list.aspx?s=47&ck=104
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/overview.html

I've looked extensively for computer for robots 2 months ago, I don't know if there is anything new since, but I don't know of any small computers with internal battery. You might have to make the power circuit yourself, or ask someone to make it.

ARM processors/computers are getting better everyday but you wont find anywhere near the support you'll find on an Intel based computer. Intel is tried and tested, plug and play.